# My formset is not valid and i cannot retreive the cleaned_data of each form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, inline-formset

I have 3 models below,

```
class MenuItem(TranslatableModel):
    item_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(MenuCategory, related_name='menu_items')
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=200),
        slug=models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True),
        description=models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True, null=True)
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(_('price'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(_('image'), upload_to='menu_items/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(_('is available'), default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('updated'), auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'.title()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('menu_management:item_detail', args=[self.item_id, self.slug])


class MenuOptionGroup(TranslatableModel):
    group_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='options_groups')
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=200),
        slug=models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    )
    is_required = models.BooleanField(_('is required'), default=False)
    max_choices = models.IntegerField(_('max choices'), blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('updated'), auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'.title()


class MenuOption(TranslatableModel):
    option_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(MenuOptionGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='options')
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=200),
        slug=models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    )
    image = models.ImageField(_('image'), upload_to='menu_options/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
    price_change = models.DecimalField(_('price change'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('updated'), auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'.title()
```

From this 3 class I am trying to create a formset that will go through the `MenuOptionGroup` and pick up their repective `menu_option`. my form look like the below.

```
class MenuOptionGroupForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    menu_option = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MenuOption.objects.none(),
                                         empty_label="No options", 
                                         required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MenuOptionGroup
        # Include the fields that should be editable in the form
        exclude = ['group_id']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and hasattr(self.instance, 'options'):
            self.fields['menu_option'].queryset = self.instance.options.all()

    def clean_menu_option(self):
        # The cleaned_data dictionary may not exist if the form hasn't been validated
        menu_option = self.cleaned_data.get('menu_option', None)
        return menu_option
```

But I get this form error.
`[{'menu_option': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'], 'name': ['This field is required.'], 'group_id': ['This field is required.']}, {'menu_option': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'], 'name': ['This field is required.'], 'group_id': ['This field is required.']}]`

Below you can see that the formset is retrieving well all the `MenuOptionGroup` and ther respective `MenuOption` but when I try to add to cart that is when I see the above error.
[frontend_add_to_cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRWPl.png)

Below, (just in case) is my view function.

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, item_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    menu_item = get_object_or_404(MenuItem, item_id=item_id)
    form = CartAddItemForm(request.POST)

    # Create a formset for the MenuOptionGroup associated with the menu_item
    formset = None
    options = []
    if 'options_groups-TOTAL_FORMS' in request.POST.keys():
        MenuOptionGroupFormSet = inlineformset_factory(MenuItem, MenuOptionGroup, form=MenuOptionGroupForm, extra=1)
        formset = MenuOptionGroupFormSet(request.POST, instance=menu_item)

    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
    if formset:
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                options.append(form.cleaned_data.get('menu_option'))
        else:
            print(formset.errors)
            print("VOILA")
    print(options)

    cart.add(menu_item=menu_item,
             quantity=cd['quantity'],
             override_quantity=cd['override']`your text`,
             options=options)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```